# GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: git

I was trying to install openfoam5 as the instructions provided here:
https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-ubuntu/

But when I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get -y install openfoam5
```

after some percents downloaded, I got this error:

```
 The following additional packages will be installed:
  paraviewopenfoam54
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openfoam5 paraviewopenfoam54
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 138 MB of archives.
After this operation, 885 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 openfoam5 amd64 20171030 [80.5 MB]
Err:1 https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 openfoam5 amd64 20171030
  GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
Get:2 https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 paraviewopenfoam54 amd64 0-3 [58.0 MB]
Err:2 https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 paraviewopenfoam54 amd64 0-3
  GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
E: Failed to fetch https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/openfoam5_20171030_amd64.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

E: Failed to fetch https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/paraviewopenfoam54_0-3_amd64.deb  GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04
What's the problem? And what's the solution?

Comment: `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install openfoam5`

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work!

Comment: Seems that the link / the url  you are using : https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/foam/foam/ubuntu is down ... could be temporary ... or forever. Suggest :  https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-ubuntu/

Comment: What do you mean by your suggestion?
What's the solution to this problem?
May you take a look at this:
https://arashmilani.com/post?id=21

How can I add these line to php code in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: OK, your url seems to work : I installed `openfoam5` on one of my Ubuntu 16.04 installs. Result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxgmcmzqzpdu18t/openfoam5.txt?dl=0 ... I don't know how you can get the »TLS packet with unexpected length« error. Did you do any changes to your OS?